# Deploying django 2.2 app on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

I wrote my app using **python 3.6** before.
Now I want deploy it on **ubuntu 20.04 and default python is 3.8**.
After creating virtual environment when I run pip install -r requirments.txt I get errors for specific packages in terminal. Here is errors for those packages:

```
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py) ... error
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
      command: /home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/cffi_5a23efe094aa4c5dbccb0ae69bfca883/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/cffi_5a23efe094aa4c5dbccb0ae69bfca883/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-2i6w3ayj
          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/cffi_5a23efe094aa4c5dbccb0ae69bfca883/
     Complete output (36 lines):

     running build_ext
     building '_cffi_backend' extension
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/c
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/c/_cffi_backend.o
     c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
        15 | #include <ffi.h>
           |          ^~~~~~~
     compilation terminated.
     error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
     ----------------------------------------
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
     Running setup.py clean for cffi
     Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
      command: /home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/pillow_d6fb8321e9754e1ca160d90143900a30/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/pillow_d6fb8321e9754e1ca160d90143900a30/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-q3h8ccal
          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/pillow_d6fb8321e9754e1ca160d90143900a30/
     Complete output (176 lines):
     running bdist_wheel
     running build
     running build_py
     creating build
     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/PIL
   
    running egg_info
     writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
     writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
     writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
     adding license file 'LICENSE' (matched pattern 'LICEN[CS]E*')
     reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
     reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
     warning: no files found matching '*.c'
     warning: no files found matching '*.h'
     warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
     no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
     writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
     running build_ext
   
   
     The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
     a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
   
     Please see the install instructions at:
        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
   
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/pillow_d6fb8321e9754e1ca160d90143900a30/setup.py", line 839, in <module>
         setup(
       File "/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
         dist.run_commands()
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
         self.run_command(cmd)
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run      self.run_command('build')
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
         self.distribution.run_command(command)
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
         self.run_command(cmd_name)
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
         self.distribution.run_command(command)
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
         cmd_obj.run()
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
         self.build_extensions()
       File "/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/pillow_d6fb8321e9754e1ca160d90143900a30/setup.py", line 674, in build_extensions
         raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
     __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
   
     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
   
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/pillow_d6fb8321e9754e1ca160d90143900a30/setup.py", line 888, in <module>
         raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
     __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
   
     The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
     a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
   
     Please see the install instructions at:
        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
   
   
     ----------------------------------------
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
     Running setup.py clean for Pillow
     Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py) ... error
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
      command: /home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/typed-ast_179d0c2213394989ae0f950fdc92fb1a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/typed-ast_179d0c2213394989ae0f950fdc92fb1a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-85kkgv7d
          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2h487j4r/typed-ast_179d0c2213394989ae0f950fdc92fb1a/
     Complete output (67 lines):
     running bdist_wheel
     running build
     running build_py
     creating build
     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
     copying typed_ast/ast3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
     copying typed_ast/ast27.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
     copying typed_ast/conversions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
     copying typed_ast/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast
     package init file 'ast3/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/tests
     copying ast3/tests/test_basics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/tests
     running build_ext
     building '_ast27' extension
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/acceler.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/acceler.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/bitset.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/bitset.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/grammar.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/grammar1.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar1.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/node.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/node.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/parser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parser.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/parsetok.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parsetok.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Parser/tokenizer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/tokenizer.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/asdl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/asdl.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/ast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/ast.o
     ast27/Python/ast.c: In function ‘ast_for_print_stmt’:
     ast27/Python/ast.c:2432:9: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
      2432 |         if (!dest)
           |         ^~
     ast27/Python/ast.c:2434:13: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
      2434 |             start = 4;
           |             ^~~~~
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/graminit.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/graminit.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/mystrtoul.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/mystrtoul.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Python/Python-ast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/Python-ast.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast27/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast27/Custom/typed_ast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/acceler.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/bitset.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/grammar1.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/node.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parser.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/parsetok.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Parser/tokenizer.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/asdl.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/ast.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/graminit.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/mystrtoul.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Python/Python-ast.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast27/Custom/typed_ast.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/typed_ast/_ast27.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
     building '_ast3' extension
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Custom
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/acceler.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/acceler.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/bitset.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/bitset.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/grammar.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/grammar.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/grammar1.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/grammar1.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/node.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/node.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/parser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/parser.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/parsetok.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/parsetok.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Parser/tokenizer.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Parser/tokenizer.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Python/asdl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python/asdl.o
     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iast3/Include -I/home/pouya795/www/marketpine-backend/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ast3/Python/ast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/ast3/Python/ast.o
     ast3/Python/ast.c:22:1: error: conflicting types for ‘_PyObject_FastCall’
        22 | _PyObject_FastCall(PyObject *func, PyObject *const *args, int nargs)
           | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     In file included from /usr/include/python3.8/abstract.h:837,
                      from /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h:147,
                      from ast3/Python/ast.c:6:
     /usr/include/python3.8/cpython/abstract.h:145:1: note: previous definition of ‘_PyObject_FastCall’ was here
       145 | _PyObject_FastCall(PyObject *func, PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t nargs)
           | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
     ----------------------------------------
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for typed-ast
```

And here is my requrements.txt file:

```
addict==2.2.1
appdirs==1.4.3
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrs==19.1.0
cached-property==1.5.1
certifi==2019.3.9
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
cryptography==2.6.1
defusedxml==0.6.0
Django==2.2
django-background-tasks==1.2.5
django-cleanup==4.0.0
django-compat==1.0.15
django-cors-headers==2.5.2
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
django-stubs==0.12.1
djangorestframework==3.9.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework-stubs==0.4.2
drf-writable-nested==0.5.4
Faker==1.0.5
future==0.17.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
inflection==0.3.1
isodate==0.6.0
itypes==1.1.0
jdatetime==3.6.2
Jinja2==2.10.1
jsonschema==3.0.1
kavenegar==1.1.2
langdetect==1.0.7
lxml==4.4.1
Markdown==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mypy==0.701
mypy-extensions==0.4.1
openapi-codec==1.3.2
Pillow==6.1.0
pyaes==1.6.1
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.7.1
Pyrogram==0.8.0
pyrsistent==0.15.4
PySocks==1.6.8
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-telegram-bot==11.1.0
pytz==2019.1
PyYAML==5.1
requests==2.21.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rope==0.14.0
ruamel.yaml==0.16.0
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.1.0
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
StringGenerator==0.3.3
swagger-spec-validator==2.4.3
text-unidecode==1.2
TgCrypto==1.1.1
typed-ast==1.3.5
typing-extensions==3.7.2
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.24.1
zeep==3.4.0
```

I think its related to 3 packages:
**cffi, Pillow and typed-ast**
Also app works fine on ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Anyone has any idea about the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
```

To fix this you should install libffi-dev.

```
 ast3/Python/ast.c:22:1: error: conflicting types for ‘_PyObject_FastCall’
```

This one is related with [this bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7001) and it seems like it can be fixed by installing/upgrading `typed-ast` and/or by upgrading python to a newer minor version.